# Asp.net single value binding from a collection

Tags: asp.net, web-services

Hello all I have a project where I need to perform single value bindings from a collection. I am trying to create an asp.net web form website with a certain degree of separation without going to mvc. Within the site I have a page that invokes a method from a web service. This method returns a result collection. The page is designed to show the data in a structured layout vs grid or form view. Can someone point me in the right direction (links or sample ) upon how to perform single value bindings against a collection result in asp.net.

**update**

Just for clarification, the method will return a collection  within that collection I have the following properties (FirstName LastName Height Weight). Is it possible to bind the collection to a section within the page and then within that section display a certain property?

```
<div id="section1" DataSource="peopleCollection">
  <%# LastName %><br/>
  <span>Height: <%# Height %></span><br/>
  <span>Weight: <%# Weight %></span>
</div>
```

I'd like to do this using web forms and a pseudo implementation of MVC without using the MVC framework

Thanks in advance

Comment: Confusion.  You are getting a collection but want to bind to a single value in it?  Which item in the collection is the single value?

Comment: @SteveWellens Steve, I have updated the question with a little more detail. Sorry for the confusion. I want to display the properties from the collection as single value pairs to control the formatting and placement of the results. I.e. a collection with three results (name height width are returned) how to go about placing them in the form.

Comment: I've done this in WPF and SL and where I am getting stuck is in asp I always did bindings to datasets. Is it possible to bind to objects in asp.net webforms in the same manner as within SL or WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is 'peopleCollection' have a single element or multiple elements where each element has properties that need to be data-bound? If yes then you should able to use data bound control such  as ListView/Repeater. What exactly is the issue here?

Or do you mean that 'peopleCollection' is really a dictionary (collection of name-value pairs) - so you have threes key into the dictionary i.e. height, wight and last-name? In such case, you can create dummy array with single element and bind it with repeater/list-view. For example,

in code-behind

```
// Assuming propertyCollection supports IDictionary<string, string>
var dummyArray = new IDictionary<string, string>[] { propertyCollection };
myControl.DataSource = dummyArray;
...
protected string GetValue(IDataItemContainer container, string propertyName)
{
   var properties = container.DataItem as IDictionary<string, string>;
   return properties[propertyName];
}
```

in mark-up

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myControl" runat="server">
 <asp:ItemTemplate>
   <div id="section1" DataSource="peopleCollection">
     <%# GetValue(Container, "LastName") %><br/>
     <span>Height: <%# GetValue(Container, "Height") %></span><br/>
     <span>Weight: <%# GetValue(Container, "Weight") %></span>
   </div>
 </asp:ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**EDIT**:
For single element (with respective properties), you can still use repeater based approach. All you have to do is to put a single element array (or any enumerable collection) and bind with the repeater (or similar control).

But really speaking, you don't really need data-binding with single element. You can also use markup such as

```
<div id="section1">
  <%= People.LastName %><br/>
  <span>Height: <%= People.Height %></span><br/>
  <span>Weight: <%= People.Weight %></span>
</div>
```

where `People` is a protected/public property exposing the single element.

Comment: The query is constructed to only return a single element that contains the properties that need to be databound. So I don't think I  need a repeater control? This implementation is more of a form where I would make a request for a person record and then need to display all the results.